# parsing multiple values from line causes error if both vaules not there

Tags: python

I've been trying to use python to extract the X and Y values from my g-code file.
  I am using example code I found here [parsing gcode file to extract coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49210059/parsing-gcode-file-to-extract-coordinates)

Both code examples there cause the same error when they encounter a line that doesn't have both X and Y in it.  The error is

```
  File "./Vac.py", line 12, in <module>
  print("{},{}".format(coord[0], coord[1]))
  IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there a way to handle this error?
Thanks
Jim

File being read

```
%  
( FILE NAME: Vacuum-chamber.01.ngc)  
( DATE/TIME: 04/November/2019 12:21:56)  
( CUTTER NUM: T1)  
( CUTTER DIA: 0.125)  
N100 G20 G17 G40 G49 G80 G90 G94  
N105 G64 P0.001  
N110 M6 T1  
N115 G0 X0.0442 Y1.0558  
N120 G0 Z0.15  
N125 G1 Z-0.25 F7  
N130 G3 X-0.0442 Y1.1442 I-0.0442 J0.0442 F10  
N135 G3 X0.0442 Y1.0558 I0.0442 J-0.0442  
N140 G1 Z0.15  
N145 G0 X-0.0442 Y-1.0558  
N150 G1 Z-0.25 F7  
N155 G3 X0.0442 Y-1.1442 I0.0442 J-0.0442 F10  
N160 G3 X-0.0442 Y-1.0558 I-0.0442 J0.0442  
N165 G1 Z0.15  
N170 G0 X1.2231 Y-1.2231  
N175 G1 Z-0.25 F7  
N180 X1.3409 Y-1.0169 F10  
N185 G3 X1.0552 Y-1.0552 I-0.1178 J-0.2062  
N190 G2 X-1.0552 Y1.0552 I-1.0552 J1.0552  
N195 G2 X1.0552 Y-1.0552 I1.0552 J-1.0552  
N200 G3 X1.0169 Y-1.3409 I0.1679 J-0.1679  
N205 G1 X1.2231 Y-1.2231  
N203 G1 Y-1.4  
N210 Z0.15  
N215 G0 Z1  
N220 M30  
%
```

code is

```
import re  
import sys  

with open('small-file.ngc') as gcode:  
    for line in gcode:  
        line = line.strip()  
        coord = re.findall(r'[XY].?\d+.\d+', line)  
        if coord:  
            print("{}, {}".format(coord[0], coord[1]))
```

Comment: Please add the indentation in the code.

Comment: Lines like `N203 G1 Y-1.4` only have one match for the regexp. What should it print for `coord[1]` on those lines?

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails on any line that only has one coordinate, since there's no `coord[1]`. You need to check for that and handle it differently.

```
if len(coord) == 1:
    print(coord[0])
elif len(coord) >= 2:
    print("{}, {}".format(coord[0], coord[1]))
```

Comment: Barmar that works,  but the Y value on line 203 is not printed which is what I wanted to do with either a lone X or Y value.  Thanks you for your help. Jim

Comment: OK, I've changed it to handle the case of one coordinate.

Comment: Yes that did it!  Thanks again  Jim